# Does the Hopper Minecart trick work on Minecraft Bedrock edtion

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-redstone

In Minecraft Java, a Minecart with Hopper will still collect items from the block immediately above that block, unlike a hopper on its own. My question is whether this still works in Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart_with_Hopper):

> A minecart with hopper pulls in items lying nearby (within a range slightly larger than the cart itself), or inside a container above the track, at a rate of up to 20 items per second, much faster than an ordinary hopper. It also picks up items that are lying on a block directly above the track. It does not push items into containers, but a hopper underneath the track can remove items from a minecart with hopper on the track. Ordinary hoppers can also drop items into a minecart with hopper like other containers, at the normal speed of 2.5 items per second.

After a quick test, yes, it does work in [minecraft-bedrock-edition](/questions/tagged/minecraft-bedrock-edition):

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does work exactly as it does in Minecraft Java edition. Placing a minecart under a block will allow you to pick up items that are on the block that the minecart is placed under. I have done this many times in things like sugarcane farms or key-card piston doors.